# Block all IPs from accessing anything on the server

Tags: iptables

I want to block all IPs except for my own home IP from doing **anything** on my server.

How can I do this with iptables? For the example lets say my home IP is 1.2.3.4

My server still needs to be able to connect to various IPs. Also by doing this will this cause any general problems?

Something like this? (doesn't work)

```
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -s 1.2.3.4 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 0.0.0.0/0 -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -d 0.0.0.0/0 -j DROP
```

Comment: If you do this, you'd better hope that your home IP address never changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Leave the `OUTPUT` chain untouched. Put these in your `INPUT` chain

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 1.2.3.4 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP    # or REJECT
```

The first rule allows your `iptables` configuration to accept traffic for established connections (i.e. those initiated by your own server to other destinations).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `/etc/hosts.deny` and `/etc/hosts.allow`.

`/etc/hosts.allow`:

```
ALL: allowed_ip
```

`/etc/hosts.deny`:

```
ALL: ALL
```

This configuration access to your server only from allowed ip (this might be a problem in some cases).
May be you have to use some `firewall` to specify access to your server.

But above will not handle `httpd` and ICMP requests you can try this:

```
# Allow your server to other destinations
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# Default Policy to DROP all incoming traffic
iptables -P INPUT DROP

# Allow traffic from source 1.2.3.4
# Add an additional rule for each allowed source
iptables -A INPUT -s 1.2.3.4 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Hi, this did not block an IP from accessing my website hosted on my VPS

Comment: I want to block everything sent to my server http, ftp, ping everything.

Comment: @Teddy291 in that case it's likely you already have some rules in your `iptables` chains that accept such traffic. Check with `iptables -nvL`.

Comment: @roaima, Teddy291 pointed about hosts.deny and it was edited after that but something does not work as expected and we do not know why.

Comment: @taliezin, you added the `iptables` rules _after_ the comment about it not blocking an IP? Ah. I couldn't see that chronology.

Comment: @roaima, that is correct. In first post of question I did not understand about ping and httpd.